# Exception casting

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am inserting different message based on the exception type.

I want to insert different custom message into the exception table based on the exception type. I cant use switch statements with exception object.

Any suggestion on how I can do this?

```
private void ExceptionEngine(Exception e)
{
    if (e.)
    {
        exceptionTable.Rows.Add(null, e.GetType().ToString(), e.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (e is NullReferenceException)
{
    ...
}
else if (e is ArgumentNullException)
{
    ...
}
else if (e is SomeCustomException)
{
    ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

and inside those `if` clauses you can cast `e` to the corresponding exception type to retrieve some specific properties of this exception: `((SomeCustomException)e).SomeCustomProperty`

Comment: Is it possible to use Swtich/case ?

Comment: @Jack, not in an acceptable way. See @Henk Holterman [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847741/exception-casting/5847799#5847799).

Comment: Thanks, I don't like dealing with strings. I think your solution is better.

Comment: @Jack: is @Huzaifa another account of yours?

Answer (score 3):

If all the code will be in the if/else blocks then better to use multiple catch (remember to put the most specific types first):

```
try {
  ...
} catch (ArgumentNullException e) {
  ...
} catch (ArgumentException e) { // More specific, this is base type for ArgumentNullException
  ...
} catch (MyBusinessProcessException e) {
  ...
} catch (Exception e) { // This needs to be last
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I cant use switch statements with exception object.

If you want to use a switch, you could always use the Typename:

```
switch (e.GetType().Name)
{
   case "ArgumentException" : ... ;
}
```

This has the possible advantage that you do *not* match subtypes.

Comment: Identifiers as strings is very ugly.

Comment: Or typeof(ArgumentException).ToString(). I'm not sure but this might be OK.

Comment: @Jack you need a constant to use switch/case. And without switch/case there is no reason to use strings at all. Another problem with this code is name collisions. Different exception classes might have the same name.

Comment: @Code: Yes it's ugly, but it meets a specific set of reqs. And you could easily add the namespace to avoid collisions. Even uglier.

Answer (score 0):

You could unify the handling of different exception types (known at compile time) by a pre-defined dictionary. For example:

```
//  Maps to just String, but you could create and return whatever types you require...
public static class ExceptionProcessor {
    static Dictionary<System.Type, Func<String, Exception> sExDictionary = 
     new Dictionary<System.Type, Func<String, Exception> {
        { 
            typeof(System.Exception), _ => {
                return _.GetType().ToString();
            }
        },
        { 
            typeof(CustomException), _ => { 
                CustomException tTmp = (CustomException)_; 
                return tTmp.GetType().ToString() + tTmp.CustomMessage; 
            }
        }
    }

    public System.String GetInfo(System.Exception pEx) {
        return sExDictionary[pEx.GetType()](pEx);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private void ExceptionEngine(Exception e) {
    exceptionTable.AddRow(ExceptionProcessor.GetInfo(e));
}
```